# php average of timestamp

Tags: php, datetime, timestamp, average

I want to calculate average of time-in for a user for particular duration , i have timestamp values for each time-in .
To calculate average i want to add all timestamps and divide by no of days .
But sum of all timestamps gives wrong input so i want convert timestamps to seconds so i can add them and calculate average .
I am using following code .

```
$timeInTotalSec = 0;
$timeInTotalSec += intval(date("H",$punchintime)) * 60 * 60;
$timeInTotalSec += intval(date("i",$punchintime)) * 60;
$timeInTotalSec += intval(date("s",$punchintime));`
```

but

```
date("H",$punchintime)
```

gives me proper value but

```
intval(date("H",$punchintime))
```

giving me **0**

Thanks in advance .

Comment: What's in `$punchintime` ? Isn't it already in seconds if it's a `TIMESTAMP` or is it a `DATE` currently?

Comment: it's a `TIMESTAMP` 
but if directly used timestamp for average its giving me wrong result .

Comment: hmm, timestamp unit is second, convert timestamp to seconds it just a non-sens... Please change your question title !

Comment: @SandipPingle correct me if I am wrong. Time-in is Punch-in-time? One user has multiple time-ins? For example, we have user that is running, and on every kilometer you record his time-in; so you need avarage time he needs for 1km?

Comment: A `timestamp` IS an integer representing the seconds elapsed since the 1st of January 1970. What do you need?

Comment: @SandipPingle show us - what format is your timestamp? If it's UNIX, then it's already seconds, if it's something else convert it to seconds using [`strtotime`](http://uk1.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) or [`DateTime`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class. You know a UNIX timestamp is time **SINCE 1st Jan, 1970** right?

Comment: @Glavić i want to calculate average for multiple days ,
i get timestamp for each day . i started by adding each of them and divide by no. of days . but its giving me wrong output . therefore i tried this non-sense. If anyone having idea to calculate average from timestamps then suggest .

Comment: Problem here is that we don't know what you are trying to do. Average for each day? But all you have is timestamp (which is date and time) on every day. How do you calculate average here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question isn't very clear, but I think I understand that you want to calculate the average punch in time from a series of punch in times.

Dates are no good for this, you need to isolate the number of seconds after midnight for each `$punchintime` and calculate the average of that. The following code does that. I created an array of times to illustrate my point, I don't know anything about your system, so generating the input array is down to you.

```
$punchInTimes = array(
    '2013-08-01 09:00',
    '2013-08-02 09:06',
    '2013-08-03 08:50',
    '2013-08-04 09:20',
    '2013-08-05 09:01',
    '2013-08-06 08:56',
);

function getAverageTime(array $times)
{
    $seconds = $average = 0;
    $result = null;
    //get seconds after midnight
    foreach($times as $dateString){
        $date = new \DateTime($dateString);
        list($datePart) = explode(' ', $dateString);
        $midnight = new \DateTime($datePart);
        $seconds += $date->getTimestamp() - $midnight->getTimestamp();
    }

    if($seconds > 0){
        $average = $seconds/count($times);
        $hours = floor($average/3600);
        $average -= ($hours * 3600);
        $minutes = floor($average/60);
        $average -= ($minutes * 60);
        $result = new \DateInterval("PT{$hours}H{$minutes}M{$average}S");
    } else $result = new \DateInterval('PT0S');
    return $result->format("%Hh %Mm %Ss");
}

echo "Average clock in time is " . getAverageTime($punchInTimes);
```

**Output:-**

> Average clock in time is 09h 00m 10s

This does not work for times that span midnight, such as an array like this:-

```
$aroundMidnight = array(
    '2013-08-01 23:59',
    '2013-08-02 00:02',
);
```

Comment: `If I get time later on I'll have a look at coping with that case.` Four years later and you have not found the time eh :-D

Comment: @Abela Apparently not :)

Answer (score 1):

What you are talking about is unixtime. Unixtime is seconds from the unix epoch (January 1, 1970). To get the time different in two timestamps you can simply minus the first timestamp from the second.

```
$timestamp1 = date('U');
```

And then some time later:

```
$timestamp2 = date('U');
```

Store these variables and when it comes time to get the difference:

```
$difference = $timestamp2 - $timestamp1;
```

You can then format the time using basic math:

```
$seconds = $difference;
$minutes = $seconds/60; 
$hours = $minutes/60;
$days = $hours/24;
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
public static function sec2hms($sec, $padHours = false) {

    // start with a blank string
    $hms = "";

    // do the hours first: there are 3600 seconds in an hour, so if we divide
    // the total number of seconds by 3600 and throw away the remainder, we're
    // left with the number of hours in those seconds
    $hours = intval(intval($sec) / 3600);

    // add hours to $hms (with a leading 0 if asked for)
    $hms .= ($padHours) ? str_pad($hours, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT) . ":" : $hours . ":";

    // dividing the total seconds by 60 will give us the number of minutes
    // in total, but we're interested in *minutes past the hour* and to get
    // this, we have to divide by 60 again and then use the remainder
    $minutes = intval(($sec / 60) % 60);

    // add minutes to $hms (with a leading 0 if needed)
    $hms .= str_pad($minutes, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT) . ":";

    // seconds past the minute are found by dividing the total number of seconds
    // by 60 and using the remainder
    $seconds = intval($sec % 60);

    // add seconds to $hms (with a leading 0 if needed)
    $hms .= str_pad($seconds, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);

    // done!
    return $hms;
}
```