# Get average time difference between a sequence of dates

Tags: php, datetime

It's an example how i calculate how many seconds between 2 date :

```
$diff = strtotime('2015-08-24 09:00:30') - strtotime('2015-08-24 09:00:15');
print_r($diff); // 15 seconds
```

Ok it's 2 date, my array look like :

```
$array = ['2015-08-24 09:00:30', '2015-08-24 09:00:15', '2015-08-24 09:00:00', '2015-08-24 09:00:45'];
```

Assumed this is comment date, how i tell you'll get comments every 15 seconds ?

Comment: Can you clarify your question?  Are you asking to get the average time difference between a sequence of dates?

Comment: I've been changing the title, thanks

Comment: Sounds simple: First get the differences, then compute the average of those differences. Did I miss something?

Answer (score 0):

Since you can already computer the difference between 2 dates, which you can put in a `diff2dates` method, you can do the following:

```
$totalDiffs = 0;

for($i = 1; $i < count($array); $i++)
{
    $diff = diff2dates($array[$i], $array[$i-1]);
    $totalDiffs += $diff;
}

$avgDiff = $totalDiffs / count($array);
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the average of the timestamps  from the below thread. 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/18512759/1235298

Let T_avg be the average timestamp, then

sum_of_diffs = mod(T_avg - T_i)     i -> 1 to n
avg_time_diff = sum_of_diffs/n