# Average Timestamp

Tags: php, timestamp, average

Referring the accepted answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18467522/php-average-of-timestamp), I have a method to calculate the average time of clocking in. How can I account for midnight case? That's the one exception of the original answer and I would really appreciate a solution.

```
$punchInTimes = array(
    '2013-08-01 09:00',
    '2013-08-02 09:06',
    '2013-08-03 08:50',
    '2013-08-04 09:20',
    '2013-08-05 09:01',
    '2013-08-06 08:56',
);

function getAverageTime(array $times)
{
    $seconds = $average = 0;
    $result = null;
    //get seconds after midnight
    foreach($times as $dateString){
        $date = new \DateTime($dateString);
        list($datePart) = explode(' ', $dateString);
        $midnight = new \DateTime($datePart);
        $seconds += $date->getTimestamp() - $midnight->getTimestamp();
    }

    if($seconds > 0){
        $average = $seconds/count($times);
        $hours = floor($average/3600);
        $average -= ($hours * 3600);
        $minutes = floor($average/60);
        $average -= ($minutes * 60);
        $result = new \DateInterval("PT{$hours}H{$minutes}M{$average}S");
    } else $result = new \DateInterval('PT0S');
    return $result->format("%Hh %Mm %Ss");
}

echo "Average clock in time is " . getAverageTime($punchInTimes);
```

EDIT: I was asked for some clarifications -

The data I'm working with is login times instead of clock-in times. I'm trying to find the average time of the day people are online. I figured that if I could find the average log out and log in time of users, I would be able to find the average time span people are online.

What I have right now is the code suggested by the answer I linked. What I've been attempting to do is add up all the DateTimes and then divide the hour, minutes and seconds by the count of the array. Am I heading in the right direction?

The application I'm developing will be accessible to users from a multitude of countries, so it's hard to set a reference time like midnight because someone could be using the application at midnight even.

EDIT 2: I realised something

I realised that the average login and logout time is not really the way to go to achieve the results I want. I came up with another solution using frequencies to find out the average time the users are online. If anyone's interested to know how I solved it I would be happy to share. :)

However, for the purposes of this question alone, the correct answer is according to what @Qirel answered so I'll accept his answer.

Comment: please add some code for understanding

Comment: I am not sure that copy-pasting someone else's answer constitutes "effort" on your behalf.  Before posting a new question, you are expected to try something.  We don't know what _your_ actual data looks like.  Do you actually have punchin times that straddle midnight? What is your exact desired output from a set of datetime values that occur near midnight? This question needs clarification/focus.  What if a person normally clocks in at 9am, but one day they clock in at 9pm? Are they 12 hours early or 12 hours late? You need to tell us your logical requirements.

Comment: I'm guessing you need the average hour/minute from the set of given dates, can you confirm that? That answer you linked seems overly complex though if that's what it does (there should be far easier ways to calculate an average). And anyway yeah, please start by showcasing what you attempted.

Comment: The expected day of clock-in needs to be the foundational point of reference -- this will determine if the time portion should gain or lose 24 hours.

Comment: Updated to fulfill the questions you guys asked.

Comment: This looks like a great example to learn test-driven development. Define some simple use cases, write tests for them, write code for them, then define more difficult use cases and write tests and the implementation. This might help you for tons of future problems

Comment: Thanks! Despite not needing to know how to find the average time anymore, I'm still curious to learn about test-driven development. Care to share any resources I can read up more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simplify this a lot, by mapping over the array, and return the number of seconds for each *time* (so you have to strip away the dates, and be left with the `H:i` format), which you can do by applying the `strtotime()` function to the times.

Once you have your new array, all you need to do is find the average number of seconds into the day the punch-in-time is at, which you can do by summing up the values in your new array, divided by the number of entries in the array.

A time of `00:00` (midnight) is at the start of the day, and this solution accounts for that.

```
$punchInTimes = array(
    '2013-08-01 09:00',
    '2013-08-02 09:06',
    '2013-08-03 08:50',
    '2013-08-04 09:20',
    '2013-08-05 09:01',
    '2013-08-06 08:56',
);

echo date('H:i', array_sum(array_map(function($v) {
        $time = date("H:i", strtotime($v));
        return strtotime($time);
    }, $punchInTimes)) / count($punchInTimes));
```

- Live demo at https://3v4l.org/JTnXT

Comment: This doesn't seem to handle well on times spanning across midnight of two different dates... e.g. '2013-08-01 00:00', '2013-07-31 23:50'. Expected average time would be 23:55. The outputted average time is 11:55.

Comment: You are only talking about punch-in times in your original question. We have no end-time to work with here. You need a pair of in and out to achieve that, of which you gave none in your answer. It's definivitely possible though, you just need a 2D array with in/out as values, then find the difference in seconds between the two dates.

Comment: But then the average would be the time spent on the application (one of the statistics I do need and have got covered). What I'm looking for in this question I asked is the time of the day they are usually online.

Comment: Modifying 

$time = date("H:i", strtotime($v));

to

date("D H:i", strtotime($v));

seems to have done the trick of working across midnight time spans.